# automaticly using someones online search database

Tags: php, search

Does anyone have any ideas for what would be the best way to automaticly use someones online search database, given a static search (see example). It might also make this question more usefull to add a solution for a none static search.

So for example, I have a website and I wan't to create a link to the PDF file of the latest report by a certain person on this site: http://aris.empr.gov.bc.ca  The search criteria does not change, all that changes is new results as the database is updated, so the search result is always http://aris.empr.gov.bc.ca/search.asp?mode=find  Notice that not all entries have a report yet.

So far my idea is to use a php script to search through the source code of the completed search result page, search for the first instance of a .pdf string, and then extract the whole link (the page is orderd by date, so the first pdf file found would be the latest report that has a pdf file available.

The problems with this solutions:
1) it is very specific to my problem and only works for a static search result, and so is not a good Q&A
2) I am not sure if the completed search link researches everytime you follow it, or if it leads to an old result that could become out to of date
3) my solution is not sexy and is held together by duct tape, if you know what I mean.

Thanks,
-Adrian

Comment: Fetch the site with `cUrl` and parse result with a `DOM` parser

Comment: Thank you sir. It looks like this is simply a matter of knowing to look up the functions you mentioned. Feel free to post as an answer so we can vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

In real terms you want to scrape the page(s).

You have 2 options in PHP:

```
1. Use CURL to fetch the page and USE PHP DOM parser to parse and extract the content from it.

2. You can use PHP Simple DOM Library, check here : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net
```

It has ready made functions and you won't need to use CURL much here.

I hope you get an idea.

Try some code, show us here and we will guide more on this...

Comment: Thank, checking that out now (I am planning way ahead on this project so it will be a while until I actually write this part of code and find out how it goes). Any idea for someone who wanted to actually perform the search to get the page in the first place? I only ask because the name of my question might attract people looking for that answer. (plus I am curious)